# How to manage dependencies between my ruby projects?

Tags: ruby, git, dependencies, bundler, gem-bundler

This sounds like a basic question, but I can't find any answer to it on the Internet.

So I have a git ruby project database_models. It's a gem. I want 3 other project to use it. I've added a dependency on this project to those 3 projects like this:

```
gem "database_models", :git => "path", :branch => master
```

Now, I want a a `develop` branch of those 3 projects to use the `develop` branch of database_models, and I want a `master` branch of those 3 projects to use the `master` branch of database_models, so that my production environment is stable and independent of my development environment.

I can see 4 options of doing this, and I don't like any of them:

1. Deploy database_models to the server, and update those 3 projects to reference database_models using a path, instead of git
2. Git submodule
3. User different versions of database_models gem (1.1, 1.2, 1.3...). I would probably need my own gem server for that, right?
4. Write some code in a Gemfile that would choose the correct branch based on the environment where "bundle install" is run.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd use [Bundler with a local path](http://ryanbigg.com/2013/08/bundler-local-paths). Your Gemfile points to the Git or Github repo using `git` or `github`:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'master'
```

Note that includes the branch. You can make each of your projects use a different branch of your gem if you want to. You can make each of your projects use a different branch of your gem if you want to. You can also use groups to deploy different versions of your gem depending on the environment:

```
group :development, :test
  gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'bleedinedge'
end

group :staging, :production
  gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'master'
end
```

The above will work fine as long as you keep pushing to the Github. But thanks to local config, you can run the following on your command line:

```
bundle config local.database_modules ~/Projects/gems/spree
```

That will add a line to your `~/.bundle/config`, so when you run `bundle` in your projects, it will pull it from your local repo.

Comment: Yes, but how do I make different branches of my project depend on different branches of my gem based on the environment or based on current project's branch? I.e., on production environment I want my project to use a master branch of the database_model gem, on test, staging, development I want develop branch to be used. I can't use local path on test, staging, because I don't want to deploy my gem to the servers

Comment: You should be able to use Gemfile groups for that, I updated my answer. (I put staging and production using master as you'd generally want staging to be on the same version as production.) If your :test is running on a server, it will still "just work". The bundle local is an optional extra to prevent fetching it from github, but the spec in the Gemfile will work in its absence.

Comment: Using Gemfile groups my first idea too. However, it doesn't seem to be possible. I get an error saying that I have duplicate versions of the same gem in my gemfile, or something like that.

Comment: Strange, I use them extensively for dev/test/etc. You can try the inline syntax in case it solves it `gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'master', group: [:staging, :production]`

Comment: [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources.
You specified that db-models (>= 0) should come from git@github.com:Comp/db-models.git (at master) and git@github.com:Comp/db-models.git (at develop)
. Bundler cannot continue.
 #  from /project/Gemfile:11
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem "db-models", :git => "git@github.com:Comp/db-models.git", :branch => "master", group: [:production]
 >  gem "db-models", :git => "git@github.com:Comp/db-models.git", :branch => "develop", group: [:development, :staging]

Comment: You can see above the error that I get when using inline syntax. Here's the discussion about the possibility of adding this feature: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/751

Comment: Wow, that's a surprising restriction. I guess the easiest workaround is just to make your own copy of the project in a completely different repo. You could still setup the original project as a remote and keep one branch in sync.

Answer (score 1):

> User different versions of database_models gem (1.1, 1.2, 1.3...). I would probably need my own gem server for that, right?

I would do this and simply have my Gemfile select the correct gem via a tag. Here is an example:
`git 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', tag: 'v5.0.0'`

So you can do the same while storing your custom gem on github (no gem server required).

[Here is how to use tags with Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

This should give you the flexibility you need.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I will either use this solution, or simply change the gem's branch from "develop" to "master" when releasing the project